# Disabling ‘Connect Automatically” in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, ethernet, internet-connection, networkmanager

Does anybody know how to disable the “Connect Automatically” feature in Network Connections\Wired\Auto eth0\Edit from the command line (Ubuntu 10.04)?

Answer (score 2):

Can you just disable these devices until needed?

That you can do from command line.

```
ifconfig interface down
```

Comment: In this case, `interface` would be `eth0`. And when you want it to connect: `ifconfig eth0 up`

Comment: bryan, that's not what I'm asking. If I did that, I would get disconnected immediately. I don't want that.

I just want to avoid connecting automatically after I disconnect, using line commands.

I should add the if I uncheck 'Connect Automatically' starting from Network Connections and then 'Wired\Auto eth0\Edit', I do not get disconnected immediately, but I do if I right-click on the Internet connection icon and start from Edit Connections...

Answer (score 1):

As I recall, all you have to do is `sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces` and "comment out" the eth0.